# cannot launch on multiple computers

Tags: ros, ssh, multi-machine

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using Ros Electric and Ubuntu 11.10

I'm attempting to run a launch file from my control computer and have some nodes run locally and some on the remote computer.

My launch files looks like this:

```
<launch>
    <machine name="Controller" address="localhost" default="true" >
        <env name="ROSLAUNCH_SSH_UNKNOWN" value="1" />
    </machine>
        <node some_local_nodes />

        <include file="$(find remote_pkg)/launch/app.launch"/>
</launch>

<launch>
    <machine name="MYREMOTE" address="MYREMOTE" default="never" user="me" password="my_password">
    </machine>

        <node machine="MYREMOTE" my_remote_app_nodes />

</launch>
```

What I get when I run my roslaunch command is:

```
remote[MYREMOTE-0] starting roslaunch
remote[MYREMOTE-0]: creating ssh connection to MYREMOTE:22, user[me]
remote[MYREMOTE-0]: failed to launch on MYREMOTE:

MYREMOTE is not in your SSH known_hosts file.

Please manually:
  ssh me@MYREMOTE

then try roslaunching again.

If you wish to configure roslaunch to automatically recognize unknown
hosts, please set the environment variable ROSLAUNCH_SSH_UNKNOWN=1


[MYREMOTE-0] killing on exit
unable to start remote roslaunch child: MYREMOTE-0
```

I know that the remote computer is in my know_hosts file and I followed the instructions [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/41446/a-is-not-in-your-ssh-known_hosts-file/) but I continue to get the same error.

I've tried it with/out passwords and with/out the ROSLAUNCH_SSH_UNKNOWN=1

Any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44974/cannot-launch-on-multiple-computers/) by [DocSmiley](https://answers.ros.org/users/2536/docsmiley/) on ROS Answers with karma: 127 on 2012-10-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-02**:
So log in on the other computer using exactly the same host name and user as specified in the launch file works and you are not asked for a password and it's in the known_hosts file with exactly that name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try " export ROSLAUNCH_SSH_UNKNOWN = 1"

---

Originally posted by [ysongros](https://answers.ros.org/users/19805/ysongros/) with karma: 16 on 2014-08-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0